# Get sender of mouseDown event

Tags: c#, user-interface, mouseevent

I need to get the sender of the mouseDown event from within the event and set it as a global variable to use in a dragDrop event, so that it calls a method depending on what picturebox was dragged. I need the control name or something. My attempt:

Global variable "dragSource":

```
public partial class MapDesignerView : Form
    {
        public Map myMap { get; set; }
        public MapController myMapController { get; set; }
        public MapConstructor myMapConstructor { get; set; }
        public MouseEventHandler myDetectMouse { get; set; }


        object dragSource = null;
```

mouseDown

```
private void pbxMinotaur_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                pbxMap.AllowDrop = true;
                pbxMinotaur.DoDragDrop(pbxMinotaur.Name, DragDropEffects.Copy |
                DragDropEffects.Move);
                dragSource = sender;
            }
```

DragDrop

```
private void pbxMap_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                if (dragSource == pbxMinotaur)
                {
                    myDetectMouse.setMinotaur(e, myMap.myCells);
                }
```

Comment: What is the issue here?
I mean what kind of problem are you facing?

Comment: The mousedown and the drag drop will both probably have the same sender as one logically follows the other. This should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what exactly isn't working... the only thing I can think that might be causing the problem is that you're storing the reference to the entire control in your drag source.

A better idea might be to just story the Id. and then test it based on the Id further down.

```
 string dragSourceName = null;


 private void pbxMinotaur_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            pbxMap.AllowDrop = true;
            pbxMinotaur.DoDragDrop(pbxMinotaur.Name, DragDropEffects.Copy |
            DragDropEffects.Move);
            Control c = (sender as Control);
            if(c != null)
                 dragSourceName = c.Name;
        }

    private void pbxMap_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dragSourceName == pbxMinotaur.Name)
        {
            myDetectMouse.setMinotaur(e, myMap.myCells);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. I get and error 'System.Window.Forms.Control does not contain a definition for "Id"'. Before i printed the sender in a label and it said system...PictureBox. I do need to get the Id or Name or something.

Comment: apologies... was in ASP mode. yeah the name property of the control is what I meant.

Comment: This worked. I've been stuck on this for a while. Thanks a bunch. Worth noting in case anyone tries this, i had to move the code from "Control c = " on, in the MouseDown method, up to the top of the method.